# How can I get started on benchpress for Angular

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-directive, end-to-end

I would like to get in to e2e testing using the benchpress framework for Angular, I found a github repository docs about it :  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/benchpress/docs/index.md

However, i was wondering if there is anymore in depth explanations out there and how i can set it up and get started with it?

Comment: http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2015/04/GettingStartedWithBenchpress.html